# How to merge multiple sequences

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sequences

I have several sequences as follows

[image]

I keep them in a list of list of strings

```
List<List<String>> Sequences;
```

I would like to merge them so that to remove sequences that are covered by other sequences. For example the sequence `V VPC VPS S` is covered by the sequence `V MV VPC VPC VPS VPA S` because the latter contains all elements of the former and in the same order (this example is not in the above lists).

I think there should be simple solutions with `Linq`, however I am not mastered with it.

My approach is to iterate the sequences and for each sequence to find sequences that their intersection with it is itself and have the same order, if so then to remove it, something like

```
foreach (var item in Sequences)
{
    if (Sequences.Any(x => x.Intersect(item).SequenceEqual(item)))
    {
        Sequences.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wan to want the collection of all collection into one ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound No, I just want to remove sequences that can be inferred from other sequences. for example you can infer the `a c f` from `a b c d e f`

Comment: You can show your not mastered approach and some master will show a more mastery one.

Comment: "the sequence `V VPC VPS S` is covered by the sequence `V MV VPC VPC VPSD VPA S` because the latter contains all elements of the former and in the same order." - No, `VPS` is in the first, but not the second.

Comment: Can you please write your lists as valid C# code? Then can you please explain in excruciating detail how to compute the relationship "covered"?

Comment: so you have a list of sequences, and each sequence has a list of elements.

if all the elements of sequence A appear in another sequence B, in the same order in B as they are in A, but not necessarily next to each other in B, then you want to remove A?

Comment: Order doen't matter I think.

Answer (score 3):

If order does matter:

```
bool IsSubsequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> subseq, IEnumerable<T> superseq)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var subit = subseq.GetEnumerator();
    if (!subit.MoveNext()) return true; // Empty subseq -> true
    foreach (var superitem in superseq)
    {
        if (superitem.Equals(subit.Current))
        {
            if (!subit.MoveNext()) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

List<List<T>> PruneSequences<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return lists
        .Where(sublist =>
            !lists.Any(superlist =>
                sublist != superlist &&
                IsSubsequence(sublist, superlist)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var Sequences = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "N", "MN", "MN", "S" },
    new List<string> { "PUNC" },
    new List<string> { "N" },
    new List<string> { "V", "VPC", "VPS", "S" },
    new List<string> { "N", "NPC" },
    new List<string> { "N", "MN" },
    new List<string> { "N", "NPA" },
    new List<string> { "ADJ" },
    new List<string> { "V", "MV", "VPC", "VPC", "VPSD", "VPA", "S" },
    new List<string> { "PREP", "PPC", "PPC" },
    new List<string> { "PRONC", "NPC" },
    new List<string> { "JONJ", "CPC", "CPC", "VPC", "VPSD", "CLR" },
    new List<string> { "CONJ" },
    new List<string> { "AUX" },
    new List<string> { "V", "MV", "VPC" },
    new List<string> { "N", "NPA", "NPC", "NPC" }
};
var PrunedSequences = PruneSequences(Sequences);
```

Result:

```
N MN MN S 
PUNC 
V VPC VPS S 
ADJ 
V MV VPC VPC VPSD VPA S 
PREP PPC PPC 
PRONC NPC 
JONJ CPC CPC VPC VPSD CLR 
CONJ 
AUX 
N NPA NPC NPC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer!

Comment: However now I think if I remove duplicate  items (that immediately follow each other) from each sequence the result was better.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sequences.Where(i=>!Sequences.Any(x => ReferenceEquals(i,x) == false && x.Intersect(i).SequenceEqual(i)));
```

Your solution might fail because it tests the item against itself?

Comment: Thanks, however it seems if I could first remove repeated items from each sequinned and then apply the solution was better